# Python Socket, send and recv with only one socket

Tags: python, sockets, networking, operating-system

I am going to implement a socket-based client-server application using python. The client sends a file to the server, and the server should get back to the client a response.

This is the code in the server side:

```
TCP_IP = 'localhost'
TCP_PORT = 9001
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
f = open("test_file", 'wb')
while True:
    data = sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not data:
        f.close()
        break
    f.write(data)
f.close()

response = Function("test_file")
self.sock.sendall(response.encode())
```

And this the code in the client side:

```
TCP_IP = 'localhost'
TCP_PORT = 9001
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))

f = open("input_file", 'rb')
while True:
    l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
    x = ''
    while (l):
        s.send(l)
        l = f.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
    if not l:
        x = s.recv(10).decode()
        print("Response: ", x)
        f.close()
        s.close()
        break
```

It works as follow. Client sends the file correctly, and the file is saved in the server side. But when the server tries to get back the response, the client doesn't accept it! If I remove the recv() function on the client, the server sends the response through my network (now I'm working locally), however, if I keep the recv() function, nothing happens. The response is calculated, my understanding is that recv() doesn't accept data. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
f = open("test_file", 'wb')
while True:
    data = sock.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
```

You are using TCP: Here the server must `listen` on the server socket and then `accept` a new connection (which means it gets a new socket) and communicate through this new socket. You cannot simply skip the `listen` and `accept` since without these the `connect` from the client will not work.

One could do such a setup with UDP (`socket.SOCK_DGRAM`) but not TCP, because TCP needs real connections with a handshake involved in connection setup and tear down. UDP instead just transfers single packets.

Comment: So you mean I cannot have a full-duplex communication through TCP sockets. Right? 
My understanding is that a socket is full-duplex interface, even it is an TCP one. In this case I need an TCP one. My other choice is to create a second socket for my responses!

Comment: @user3890487: Of course one can have a full-duplex communication through TCP socket. That's used everywhere. But it cannot done the way you do it. Instead you need to `listen` and `accept` on the server socket - and then you get a new *connected* socket which is full-duplex.

Comment: When I tried to _connect_ again, I get an error in server side saying the socket is already connected.
On client side, if I listen in client, it returns this error:
`OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`

Comment: @user3890487: I have no idea what you are doing. But I recommend to study a [basic introduction](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+tcp+client+server) how to create a TCP server and client in Python. It looks for me that you are still missing a basic understanding how it is supposed to work.